# Invalid Syntax ; probably simple to fix

Tags: python, syntax

This is the part of my code which doesn't work. It says "there's an error in your code: invalid syntax." 
edit: this is the part of code that is broken: for i in range(0, len(marks)):

```
def histogram(data):


def getFrequency(marks):
    freqList = []
    for i in range(0,101):
        freqList.append(0)

for i in range(0, 101):
    starsList = []
    for i in range(0, data[i]):
        starsList.append("*") 
    pad
    if data[i] < 10:
        pad = " "
    elif data[i] < 100:
        stars = "" .join(starsList)
    print("%d | %s %d" %(i, starsList)






for i in range(0, len(marks)):  
    mark = marks[i]
    freqList[mark] += 1

return freqList


freq = getFrequency(marks)
mode = maximum(freq)

#print (freq)
```

this is the rest of the code (which is above the part with the error). It may or may not be riddled with errors. I put it here in case it is relevant.

```
import random

def bubbleSort(data):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,len(data) - 1):
        for j in range(0, len(data) - 1):
            count += 1
            if data[j] > data[j+1]:
                #swap
                temp = data[j]
                data[j] = data[j + 1]
                data[j + 1] = temp
    print(count)
    return data

data = [5,4,3,2,1]
data = bubbleSort(data)
print(data)



def getData():

    data = []

    for i in range(0, 100):
        data.append(random.randint(0,100))
    return data




def mean(data):

    total = 0

    for i in range (0, len(data)):
        #add data[i]
        total = total + data[i]

    return total/ len(data)


def maximum(data):

    maximum = data[0]

    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        if maximum < data[i]:
            maximum = data[i]

    return maximum



def minimum(data):

    minimum = data[0]

    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        if minimum > data[i]:
            minimum = data[i]

    return minimum

#def mode(data):


marks = getData()
```

Comment: Your indentation is totally off. Did you mean to have the whole first part in the histogram function or is the histogram function supposed to be separate?

Comment: Fix the formatting and indicate which line the interpreter blamed for the syntax error.

Comment: You need a pass statement under the histogram function declaration too

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing a right parenthesis here:

```
print("%d | %s %d" %(i, starsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a parenthesis in print line, inside for cicle:

```
for i in range(0, len(marks)):
    ....
    print("%d | %s %d" %(i, starsList))
```